# Java method called with reflection only. Annotate?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have a bunch of classes named Process0, Process1, Process2 etc. inherited from a base class Process. Every child class includes the same static method. Future implementations may add more "ProcessNN".

I have to iterate all classes and call the same method from every class for specific data. 
It happened this static method is never called directly, only with reflection.

How can I mark/annotate this method in every class to remove warnings over "never used method" and preserve it from automatic code optimization?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not make it public, if it's called from outside the class?

Comment: It is public. But code optimizers consider those methods "never used".

Comment: @OGP Which code optimizer? Usually there should be no warning when public methods are not used. Depending on the optimizer you might need to mark them as public API to avoid those warnings.

Comment: For example I use IntelliJ and it always report those methods as unused. I added the annotation from below and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation to suppress compiler (and most IDE) warnings.